# Multiple ViewModels in View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, grid, viewmodel, kendo-ui

I'm looking to display two Telerik Kendo grids with different information(models) in one view and I'm not sure how to do it.

Model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace KendoUIMvcApplication1.Models
{
    public class Car
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Truck
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
         public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Vehicles
    {
        public IEnumerable<Car> CarCol { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Truck> TruckCol { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller (Creating some test objects):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using KendoUIMvcApplication1.Models;

namespace KendoUIMvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var carList = new List<Car>();
            var truckList = new List<Truck>();
            var vehCol = new Vehicles();

            var car1 = new Car
            {
                Id = 1, 
                Name = "Passat"
            };
            var car2 = new Car
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Passat"
            };
            carList.Add(car1);
            carList.Add(car2);

            var truck1 = new Truck
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "S10"
            };
            var truck2 = new Truck
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Blazer"
            };
            truckList.Add(truck1);
            truckList.Add(truck2);

            vehCol.CarCol = carList;
            vehCol.TruckCol = truckList;

            return View(vehCol);
        }
    }
}
```

View (Here I'm trying to display the two grids. The first one for cars and the second one for trucks):

```
@using KendoUIMvcApplication1.Models

@model IEnumerable<Vehicles>

@*// Car Grid*@
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Id);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Name);
    })
)

<div></div>

@*// Truck Grid*@
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model))
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(t => t.Id);
        columns.Bound(t => t.Name);
    })
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model should be of type `Vehicles`:

```
@model Vehicles
```

Then you can access the two collections:

```
@Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.CarCol)
...
```

and

```
@Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.TruckCol)
...
```

Comment: Thank you. I had been changing around my code and overlooked that.

Is this the recommended way to display multiple ViewModels within one view?

Comment: You're welcome and yes, your `model` should include the main data required by your view.