# Multiple View Models with Business Logic

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Based off of the example located here:

[Multiple ViewModels in View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769958/multiple-viewmodels-in-view/25507753#25507753)

Can anyone show this example without adding the individual items but by showing a datasource. So for instance if my business Logic layer has the means to pull the customer address then my two models would be CustomerInfo & CustomerLocations - doing it this way I am having trouble with the last line shown (the .Add) .. I tried removing the ToList but either way it says I have invalid arguements - my ViewModel class looks exactly like the example.

```
var ccus = new List<ViewModel.CustomerInfo>();
var cloc = new List<ViewModel.CustomerLocations>();
var cust = new ViewModel.Customers();
var cI1 = new Business.CustomerLogic.BLCustomerAddress();
cI1.LoadCustomerAddress(decryConcept, decryBnumber, intCustid).ToList();
ccus.Add(cI1);
```

In the previous example he declares the code inline

```
var car1 = new Car
        {
            Id = 1, 
            Name = "Passat"
};
```

I want to replace this piece with a call to my Business Logic

I have no reference to the BusinesLogic model in the new ViewModel I have setup per the example and perhaps this is where I need to tie the two objects together.  Here is my code for that piece.

```
public class ViewModel 
{ public class Customers 
{ public IEnumerable<CustomerInfo> CInfo { get; set; } 
  public IEnumerable<CustomerLocations> CLoc { get; set; } 
} 
 public class CustomerInfo
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string AccountNo { get; set; }
    public bool Active { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
.........
```

Comment: "I have no reference to the BusinesLogic model in the new ViewModel I have setup per the example and perhaps this is where I need to tie the two objects together. "  You shouldn't have any references there.  In your Controller you want to tie the two together - create a view model, create a business logic model, populate the view model from the business logic model

Answer (score 0):

ccus is of type `List<ViewModel.CustomerInfo>` so the add method expects a ViewModel.CustomerInfo but you are passing in `cI1` which is of type `Business.CustomerLogic.BLCustomerAddress`.  Calling `ToList()` won't do anything as you are not storing the result of `LoadCustomerAddress`, so turning the result into a list has no affect on anything.

Comment: If you could show more code I might be able to help more.  Try following the example of the question you linked to as it is clear from the code he posted what the problem was.  It might be better to edit your answer rather than posting code in comments, it is only really useful for very short snipets.

Comment: Okay I tweaked my answer and may have been more clear now.  Please let me know if you need any more code.  I get the ViewModel class to tie together two Models - just not clear on how this works with my business logic.  Thanks @Ben Robinson

Comment: did you glance at this again?

Comment: I'm afraid the extra information you have added doesn't really help.  Can only add an instance of CustomerInfo to the CInfo property on your class. You have not provided any information that would allow me to understand WHERE the information would come from to allow you to create an instance and set the properties to the relevant values.